# Unable to scrape the content though it appears in the inspect element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape the user reviews from the cnet page. The pros and cons of the user reviews information. (http://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-galaxy-s7/user-reviews/)

I have used selenium to dynamically load the page but still the html source and inspect element source are different. I also have used requests to get the source code. I am not sure about the difference in between the two.

Can you please suggest me a work around?

The code used for selenium:

```
driver.get("http://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-galaxy-s7/user-reviews/")
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
soup= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
```

requests code:

```
try:
    r = requests.get("http://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-galaxy-s7/user-reviews/", timeout = 10)
except Exception,e:
    print("borken")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
```

PS: I gave a search in stack overflow and google, but I couldn't find a working answer. It would also be helpful if anyone can give me a link.

Comment: Could you show what code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

That page has quite a bit of JavaScript so I think using selenium is going to be your best bet to load all of the content. In your current code you are only waiting 2 seconds which may not be enough time. I would recommend using an explicit wait that returns when the comment section elements have completely loaded.

There is a good explanation and example here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

It looks like each of the comment blocks have the form

```
<article class= "fyre-comment-article fyre-comment-source-0"..../>
```

so you could start by modifying the example from the above link like this: (I don't have the ability to actually run this code on my current machine so just use it as an example of a way to modify the code from the link. Read here for more ways to locate elements: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = <yourdriver>
driver.get("http://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-galaxy-s7/user-reviews/")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
        '//article[class="fyre-comment-article fyre-comment-source-0"]'))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```